# No visible @interface for UIViewController declares the selector 'initWithFrame:'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a problem with this code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "WheelMovementProtocol.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

}

@property int wheelNumberOfSections;
@property (weak, nonatomic)     id      <WheelMovementProtocol> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic)   UIView  *containerView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andDelegate:(id)del withSections:(int)sectionsNumber;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {

}

- (void)drawWheel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize containerView;
@synthesize wheelNumberOfSections;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andDelegate:(id)del withSections:(int)sectionsNumber {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame: frame])) { // Here's the error
        self.wheelNumberOfSections = sectionsNumber;
        self.delegate = del;

        [self drawWheel];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawWheel {
    self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: self.frame];
    CGFloat angleRadius = 2 * M_PI / wheelNumberOfSections;

    for (int i = 0; i < wheelNumberOfSections; i++) {

    }
}
```

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit) of how to create a rotating wheel control and I'm following step by step but I can't understand why my code is wrong

Comment: `UIViewController` doesn't have a method called `initWithFrame:`. So you can't do `[super initWithFrame:frame]` if your object inherits from `UIViewController`.

Comment: Your superclass is UIViewController in tutotial they subclassing from UIControl

Comment: "The solution was to follow the tutorial again and to correctly create the ViewController." this is hilarious :-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this statement [super initWithFrame:frame];
Because initWithFrame is UIView init method you can change it like

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andDelegate:(id)del withSections:(int)sectionsNumber 
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:"your nib for view controller" bundle:nil]))
    { 
      // Here's the error
      [self.view setFrame:frame];
      self.wheelNumberOfSections = sectionsNumber;
      self.delegate = del;

      [self drawWheel];
    }

    return self;
}
```